# HTML use Steam API to get price

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

I want to display the Cost of one Case on my Page. 
The Steam API is: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%202%20Case

How can i use the String that is given by this Link ?

I tried things like:

Comment: This is Json. Google and find what you need.

Comment: Laurin, your question is going to be closed really soon because your question lacks code or any attempt whatsoever at achieving your goal. I hope you have some code to share with us really soon or else this question will be closed. Thanks.

Comment: please edit your question to say what you are trying to accomplish. You can simply "use" the String by saving it to a file, or perhaps you meant you want to access the value of a certain field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First maybe you want to look those pages: 
For getting a page content with *file_get_contents*:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

And decode the json data with *json_decode* :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%202%20Case");
    $decode = json_decode($json,1);
    echo $decode['median_price'];
```